# How can I add two more column beside the sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I can't create another two column beside the sidebar.

[image: Please see the image for understanding]

Can somebody assist me?

```html
<!-- -------------Navigation Bar------------- -->

<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#services">Example 1</a>
  <a href="#portfolio">Example 2</a>
  <a href="#about">Example 3</a>
  <a href="#contact">Example 4</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.
    </p>
    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
    <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit with your CSS as well.

Comment: I have done some changes in your code and commented "her is my changes" like that please check that is helpfull to you >> https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MdQR30jTRMAzc-ARYoh

Comment: As well as if you want to add another column please add another DIV element inside the class ="myDIV" that I created , Then you can see 3 columns

Comment: When I reduce my screen size below 768px and below 500px (check- https://ibb.co/3RQNV5F / https://ibb.co/pwmncr7) it is working fine, but the problem occurs when it goes desktop view which is above 768px (https://ibb.co/DMF0pXc)

Here is my full code- https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MdQn5VKDCcCLefC-mgW

Comment: @KevinMac Can you please checkout my latest comment. I hope u can solve it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this you can adjust width according to requirement

create 2 div and style it as you want here i provided just an example

```css
.section1{
    background-color:#00ffff;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    border-right: 1vw solid #F5E5D6; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.section2{
    background-color:#f1c40f;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#services">Example 1</a>
  <a href="#portfolio">Example 2</a>
  <a href="#about">Example 3</a>
  <a href="#contact">Example 4</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="section1">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.
    </p>
    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="section2">
    2nd screen
</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want this 3 column in the same row. this is the problem please see (https://ibb.co/ngTQX7t)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by wrapping your content in a container that would behave like a row and its children will be aligned as columns. You can do this with `display: flex` or `display: grid`, your choice.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%; */
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%
}

.content {
  width: 60%
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#services">Example 1</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Example 2</a>
    <a href="#about">Example 3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Example 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>
      This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.
    </p>
    <p>
      We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links
    </p>
    <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-2">
    Another container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can check my full code here - https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MdQR30jTRMAzc-ARYoh

Comment: I appreciate your afford, but its not what i want, Can u please check my full code here- https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MdQR30jTRMAzc-ARYoh

Comment: You don't need this much nesting of containers in your code. Kindly go through [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). You can also switch directions on media query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#services">Example 1</a>
                <a href="#portfolio">Example 2</a>
                <a href="#about">Example 3</a>
                <a href="#contact">Example 4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="section1">
                <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
                <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
                <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section2">2nd screen</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added new DIV element please check that and get some idea. I have edited this related to your code.

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.header{                /* Header */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(/assets/top.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: right;
    
}
   
.fa{                     /* icon color */
    color: white;
}
.comLink:hover{          /* icon hover */
    color: #ccc;
}

input{                  /* Search input*/
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding:6px ;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn{                   /* Search Button */
    padding: 7.5px;
    background:#f44336 ;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn:hover{                /* Button hover */
    background: #FF7F50;
}
.links a{
    padding-left: 19px;
}

.logo{                      /* Logo */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   padding: 40px 0px;
   font-size: 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 8px;
}
span{
    color: #f44336;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.myDIV{         /* here is my changes */
  display:flex;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}
   
.sidebar {
  display:flex; /* here is the changes */
  flex-direction:column; /* here is the changes */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar a {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Content */


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
.myDIV{      /* here is my changes */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.sidebar{   /* here is my changes */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {
      float: left;
    }
  div.content {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

  .logo{
      font-size: 25px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .logo{
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: normal;
  }
}

.section1{
    background-color:#00ffff;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    border-right: 1vw solid #F5E5D6; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.section2{
    background-color:#f1c40f;
    width:28%;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hi There! Aziz</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- -------------Header/Banner------------- -->

        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="logo">ABDUL <span>AZIZ</span></a>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#"><i class="comLink fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="comLink fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="comLink fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="comLink fa fa-behance-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                <form action="#">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- -------------Navigation Bar------------- -->
    <div class ="myDIV">              <!-- here is the DIV I added-->
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#services">Example 1</a>
            <a href="#portfolio">Example 2</a>
            <a href="#about">Example 3</a>
            <a href="#contact">Example 4</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="section1">
                    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
                    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen
                        size
                        is
                        700px or less.
                    </p>
                    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack
                        and
                        center the navigation links.</p>

                </div>
                
                <div class="section2">
                    2nd screen
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>                
     </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have commented "here is my changes" like that to find my changes

[Updated the answer please check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/z8spcbo7/24/)

Comment: Dear kavin thanks for your reply, but thing is my sidenavbar should be responsive. when my screen goes under 768px the side navbar should go up. Please check the image here-https://ibb.co/RvN6Ypp
https://ibb.co/cNkKH75

Comment: I have updated my answer check this I think that is the solution which you want. check JSfiddle there Zoom in and Out see side bar is changing . I have mentioned " /* here is my changes */" infront of the changes >> http://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/z8spcbo7/24/

Comment: There want to do small css changes and want to add a DIV element inside the container , That DIV cover the SideBar and content . see that and get the idea